# Emulate Google Chat's "Person says..." In title

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a RSS client and i think it would be really cool if the title of the page could update with an alert of a new item. So if the user in on a different tab to my site, the tab's content would change to "New" or whatever. This is emulating Google's Chat system where it updates with "Joe Says..." in the title/tab.

How would i go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.title = 'New';
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JCVu2/show/

Answer (score 3):

This would be as simple as changing the title value:

```
$("title").text("Jason says:");
```